# How to keep image size consistent in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these four images that are responsive. But, there are times when the images don't look right because of the size of the window. An example is this:

[image]

How do I make the images responsive *and* keep the proportion of the images?

```css
#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_div img {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt=""  style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1328767473l/10713286.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1394566113l/20454074.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1460309528l/44652.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End of Books -->
```

Comment: The images have fixed width and height. I don't see how that's responsive. If you want to keep the fixed dimensions, just put values there that match the original proportions.

Comment: @JJJ Bootstrap makes it responsive. Try playing with the code snippet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One image is not of equal dimension.

```css
#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_div img {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  min-height: 310px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1328767473l/10713286.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1394566113l/20454074.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1460309528l/44652.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have updated the code, Please don't use min-width. In fact if you want it to responsive then don't need to specify the width or height. img-responsive class will handle the responsiveness

Comment: How do I make all the images the same dimensions even if one is not of equal dimension? That is why I set the `width` and `height`. Is there a way to use Bootstrap and use dimensions? :)

Comment: Yes then you can use min-height property like i use above, and edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

For the images to be responsive you'll need to set the images to have a `width: 100%` and keep the `height` property untouched. This way the images will keep their proportions, but they will get reduced height as their containers gets smaller and smaller.

Another thing you can do is set those images as `background-image` and also `background-size: cover`. This way, you can set `height` to a fixed amount, and the image will not be distorted - but they will get cropped out to fit the available container space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using aspect ratio

```
 <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
//Image here
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
 //Image here
</div>
```